# Firefox OS: Background service, manifest option "background_page" not working

Tags: mobile, firefox-os, background-service

I am currently trying to set up a background service for my app so that the app will be opened when the phone has been turned on. If I am not mistaken if the webapp's manifest contains the "background_page" then the background service should be running automatically without the app being open. Currently the background service is not running.

**manifest**

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "Hello World",
  "description": "Hello World",
  "orientation":"portrait-primary",
  "icons": {
    "16": "/icons/icon_16.png",
    "32": "/icons/icon_32.png",
    "48": "/icons/icon_48.png",
    "128": "/icons/icon_128.png"
  },

  "permissions":{
    "background":{},
    "backgroundservice":{},
    "desktop-notification":{},
    "webapps-manage":{}
  },

  "launch_path": "/index.html",
  "background_page":"/background.html",

  "developer": {
    "name": "Charlie Hudson"
  },
  "default_locale": "en"
}
```

**background**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        navigator.mozApps.mgtm.getSelf().launch();
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell `background_page` was a property that was used around 2012 to facilitate this behavior but it has been retired before 1.0 came out. At least I can't find any references to it anymore. I don't have hard evidence on it though. Anyway, there are a couple of things you can do to create this behavior:

1. [Push notifications](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/SimplePush) and do syncing there. But it really depends on the data
2. [Alarms](https://github.com/janjongboom/app-training-dhaka/blob/master/alarm/alarm.js). You can schedule an alarm every minute, when the app is killed by the OS it will come back alive through the alarms API. Downside is that if you miss the alarm (f.e. because the phone is off) the OS will just throw it away. So schedule a lot of them :p

There is no proper way of implementing this behavior afaik.

Also note that access to sensors is limited when not running as front process.